# Testing Angular Material 6: Unexpected value 'PropDecoratorFactory' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-material2

While testing an Angular Material 6.0.1 component, I'm getting this error:

> Unexpected value 'PropDecoratorFactory' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

There are no problems when executing the app in the browser so I guess the error is related to TestBed configuration:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [
    ChipInputAutoCompleteComponent,
    MatAutocomplete,
    MatFormField,
    MatOption,
    MatChipList,
    MatChip,
    MatIcon,
    Input
  ],
  providers: []
})
```

And the template:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width-container">
<mat-chip-list #chipList (click)="openPanel(chipAutoComplete, chipInput)">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of chips" [selectable]="true" [removable]="true" (removed)="removeChip(chip)">
        {{chip[displayPropertyKey]}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="true">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <div [formGroup]="chipFormGroup">
        <input [placeholder]="inputPlaceholder" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true" [matAutocomplete]="chipAutoComplete"
         formControlName="inputFormControl" (click)="openPanel(chipAutoComplete, chipInput)" (keyup)="chooseFirstItem($event.key, chipAutoComplete)"
         #chipInput />
    </div>
</mat-chip-list>
<mat-autocomplete #chipAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="addChip(chipInput)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option[displayPropertyKey]">
        <span>{{option[displayPropertyKey]}}</span>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

This is the full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xas7g2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchip-input-auto-complete%2Fchip-input-auto-complete.component.spec.ts The components' implementation is missing because I think it is not relevant for this kind of error (I'm getting the same error while testing it locally with my fully implemented component).